# Is it possible to send a html page with application installation package in adobe flex?

Tags: apache-flex, installation, package

I want to send a html webpage with my application in installation package,is it possible?

Comment: can you please explain a bit more?
I don't quite understand what you wish to accomplish

Answer (score 0):

If you put the HTML file in the src folder or some folder in that src folder, when making the release you will have the option to check or uncheck if you want to add that file to the final install .air file.